Axios throws net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error when call API method
I got net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE whenever API get called. It is a XHR request error
I used to run my node backend locally and it works fine. Now, I try to containerize it via docker. There are two containers: front and backend. I have no problem with my react frontend. Only node backend has the aforemention issue.
Here is my API post request function:
const signInCurrentUser = async (username, password) => {
    try {
        const response = await axiosInstance.post("/users/signin", {
            username,
            password,
        });

        console.log("Signed-in user: ", response);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error: ", error);
        // Check if the error has a response object
        if (error.response) {
            if (error.response.status === 400) {
                throw new Error("Invalid username or password");
            } else {
                throw new Error(
                    `Sign-in failed with status code ${error.response.status}`
                );
            }
        } else if (error.request) {
            // The request was made but no response was received
            throw new Error("No response received from the server");
        } else {
            // Something happened in setting up the request
            throw new Error(`Error in request setup: ${error.message}`);
        }
    }
};

It throws the error object from error.request and error.response is undefined since it is empty. So, I assume it might be some error with some instructions in dockerfile? or need more configuration? (please guide me)
Belows are dockerfiles lies in my front/backend:
# Build the express app
FROM node:20 AS build

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /booking-express

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (or yarn.lock)
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies (including development dependencies)
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Production
FROM node:20-alpine

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /booking-express

# Copy only the necessary files from the build stage
COPY --from=build /booking-express /booking-express

# Install only production dependencies
RUN npm install

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 4000

# Define the command to run the application
CMD ["node", "./api/index.js"]


# Build the React app
FROM node:20 AS build

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /booking-react

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application files
COPY . .

# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Serve the built files with Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy the build files to the Nginx directory
COPY --from=build /booking-react/build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 80    
EXPOSE 80

# Start Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

I use docker build to build from the instructions. To run containers I just use command: docker run -p 4000:4000 --env-file .env booking-express and docker run -p 80:80 --env-file .env booking-react without docker-compose.yaml because I'm really new to docker. The env is also included in container as I checked with docker -it I have MySQL as a database and it seems to have a problem connection to it during API request.
I'd like to check some log in the backend, but the only thing it shows is payload (I also have no clue why I see it. It shows in backend when I run backend container) because it seems like the connection is refused by server or something. I can see log in container:
Server is running on port 4000
username:  test-user
{
  user_id: 1,
  password: 'hashed pw'
}

It displays username:  test-user before the code would used to typically execute pool.query() (to connect to MySQL DB). I just want to know why there is no response coming back.

Is your axiosInstance configured with a baseURL or are you actually making a host-relative request with axiosInstance.post("/users/signin"? If baseURL, what value is used? If not, how are requests supposed to be proxied to the Express service?

Yes, baseURL: http://server_ip:4000/

Seeing as you're just using the vanilla nginx:alpine image with no configuration overrides, I'm guessing you're not running a proxy. You'd need to set your React app Axios requests to go to http://localhost:4000

This question is similar to: Fail to resolve docker compose service name from front end. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

FYI Docker Compose is really easy to use. It makes running multiple images in concert an absolute breeze. Highly recommend you give it a try

Sorry, I get a bit confused. Isn't it the same using localhost and server_ip if I running both of front and backend locally? I change the baseURL to localhost and it shows the same result.

"I change the baseURL to localhost"... it should be exactly "http://localhost:4000/". Are you able to make a curl or Postman request to your Express service when it's running in Docker? Eg curl -v -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"username":"whatever","password":"whatever"}' 'http://localhost:4000/users/signin'

Also when you make changes, are you rebuilding your images?

I can't curl but with postmon it shows { success: false, message: "Invalid username or password", } which is response I include in pool.query() but with valid sign in the container seems to refuse to connect and no response from the server

Yes I already rebuild images

That sounds like a problem with your Node.js service. You'd need to check its logs and if you want help with it, [edit] your question to include details. You also haven't shown how your database fits into the picture. Is it also running in a container? If so, how is networking configured (hint: this is something Docker Compose handles very well)? What connection details are you using in your Node.js app?

I already fixed it by changing from backend dockerfile from image alpine to slim and it works..
